# Xamarin forms changes color of png icons by itself

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Icons with PNG extension are white, but xamarin forms also show up in another color. Just buttons and menu

Comment: Hi. Your question is not very clear. But if you want to change the color of a png icon, you can use [Xamarin Community Toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Effects/IconTintColor) Effect IconTintColor.

Comment: Thank you Juan I was able to change the color

Comment: Great, in that case I will elaborate a little further as an answer. If that worked for you then you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I order to change the color of an image, Xamarin Community Toolkit offers an Effect called [Icon Tint Color](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Effects/IconTintColor)

By adding the Effect to an Image View, you can change the color of the image.

This will work better for png images that are white and have transparency.

You can check the [Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/samples/XCT.Sample/Pages/Effects/IconTintColorEffectPage.xaml) to have a better knowledge on how to use it

```
<Image
     Source="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/48/48639.png"
     xct:IconTintColorEffect.TintColor="Red" />
```